# I would like to get all specific values from a dictionary based on a value

Tags: python

I have huge dictionary like this

{0: {'age': 19, 'sex': 'female', 'bmi': 27.9, 'children': 0, 'smoker': 'yes', 'region': 'southwest', 'charges': 16884.924}, 1: {'age': 18, 'sex': 'male', 'bmi': 33.77, 'children': 1, 'smoker': 'no', 'region': 'southeast', 'charges': 1725.5523}

and so on... I would like to take all the ages and calculate the mean for example based on the region...
I tried with a function and loop it through the dct and if region == (the ones I want) it returns the mean, I think I am far away from my goal.. any ideas please?

I would like to do it without import anything

thank you.

Comment: Please add the code you tried, the result, and explain us what's wrong

Comment: @Christophe thank you for your interest, I sorted out because my mistake was looping all over the dct instead his values, it wasnt necessary loop all over .. thats why I didnt get it... :) thank again for you help

Answer (score 1):

You can access all values seperately in loop and calculate the mean with this code;

```
for value in yourDict.values():
        if value["region"]=="Region You Want":
            #calculate the mean in there
            #you can access the all ages value["age"]
```

Or basically, you can create a list by querying the regions and calculate the average of the resulting list with this code;

```
ageList=[value["age"] for value in myDict.values() if value["region"]=="southeast"]
print(sum(ageList)/len(ageList))
```

Comment: thank you I took a long way around with no sense.. wunderbar!

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to first loop once to filter the given dataset and create a dictionary of lists with the region as keys

Then loop through the crated dictionary and compute the mean of the values in the list

```
mean_ages = {}

for data in d.values():
    region = data['region']
    if region not in mean_ages: mean_ages[region] = [] #Create empty list to store ages
    mean_ages[region].append(data['age'])

for region in mean_ages:
    l = mean_ages[region]
    mean_ages[region] = sum(l)/len(l)
```

It is probably more efficient to run these loops once and then you have it generated for all regions and if you need a value for a specific region, you can just read the dictionary.

Comment: that's good as well, you've done the check and if the values are the ones you put them into a list and ta-da! thank you for showing me this approach

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).